# How to find coefficient of $s^{12}t^{13}$ in the expansion of $(2s-3t)^{25}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am trying to find the coefficient of $s^{12}t^{13}$ in the expansion of $(2s-3t)^{25}$.

I don't know if I am doing right, but I know we have to start with $\binom{25}{12}$. When $t^{13}$ is added, becomes more confusing. Any help in handling this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general term is given by $${{25}\choose r}(2s)^r (-3t)^{25-r}$$

You need $r=12$: $${{25}\choose {12}} (2s)^{12} (-3t)^{13} = -{{25}\choose{12}}\cdot 2^{12}\cdot 3^{13} s^{12}t^{13}$$

Comment: why the value of r is set to 12?

Comment: @user102859 Because you need the power of $s$ to equal $12$, and in my general term, $s$ is raised to the $r$th power.

Comment: I checked an online youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPmrvRiTruw
based on it they use r = 13, not r = 12....

Comment: @user102859 They must have used a different general expression, either way you’ll get the same answer.

Comment: makes sense. Thanks.